# Can't start activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Tried to start an activity from fragment but it doesn't works and I can't find the problem 
and there isn't answer in community from other questions worked
when clicks in tn (button7) nothing happens
tried in 2 emulators and huawei phone

**sst.java (the fragment) **

```
public class sst extends Fragment {
Button btn ;
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"اختر مادة الكتاب",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false);
    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BooksExploreActivity.class) ;
            intent.putExtra("subj" , "3olomTabe3ya") ;
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false);
}
```

}

**fragment_sst.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/monadi"
    android:text="اختر مادة الكتاب"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fragmentsbutton"
    android:text="العلوم الطبيعية"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fragmentsbutton"
    android:text="الرياضيات"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/button8" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And thanks .

Comment: Is `BooksExploreActivity` also the Activity holding your Fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the problem is that you make a logic with the View v, but then you return another then you must change this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false);
    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BooksExploreActivity.class) ;
            intent.putExtra("subj" , "3olomTabe3ya") ;
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false); // change this
}
```

to:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false);
    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BooksExploreActivity.class) ;
            intent.putExtra("subj" , "3olomTabe3ya") ;
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v; // here is where the change is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sst, container, false);
```

with

```
return v;
```

With your solution you are returning the original view without the "custom action" on the button.